# Returning a value while unlocking in finally{}

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I wonder if this code is thread-safe:

```
public class SafeSequenceWithLock implements Sequence {

  private int value = 0;
  Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  @Override
  public int getAndIncrement() {
    lock.lock();
    try{
        value++;    
        return value;
    }finally{
        System.out.println("XXX");
        lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Will the locked Lock persist until after returning the value or will this just be the same as using ...

```
lock.lock();  
value++;
lock.unlock();
// another thread could change "value" here!
return value;
```

...?

Comment: You are using the recommended form. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html The two snippets are in fact **not** equivalent. From a "happens-before" - perspective in positive case - yes. But in case of failure, the lock may not be released in second snippet.

Comment: Well of course the latter way of doing it is not safe for exceptions. I could wrap this one in a try{}catch{} as well. The question is though, if another thread can intervene before returning the value if i put the return into a finally{}-statement.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example, it will be the same as you mentioned: the lock will be unlocked and **then** the value will be returned: the finally block is called just before the method returns.

Comment: They are **not** the "same". This example is trivial but generally, you could have an exception, leaving the lock locked in the snippet without try/finally.

Comment: I was not referring to a generic situation but straight to the provided example. For the code the OP provided, it **is** the same. But, good point, I'll edit the answer to show this!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So both are not safe from an intervening thread, right?

Comment: No, you should keep the result of the ++ in a local variable, and return that one. E.g: `int localValue = value++; return localValue;`